# Sending asynchronous information with node.js and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have the following problem: I'm trying to send data collected by AMI (asterisk.io) using the sockets.io module, but I'm having difficulty to printing it in the html file. In the code below, the idea was to show it on the console as the data came in. I really do not know how to make this work, can anyone help me? Thank you!

html file:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  socket.on('data', function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
</script>
```

asterisk.io with socket.io file:

```
var socket = require('../app');
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 1000;
var aio = require('asterisk.io');

var io = socket.io;
var ami = null;
ami = aio.ami(
    '192.168.0.7',
    5038,
    'admin',
    'admin'
);
ami.on('error', function(err){
    throw err;
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  ami.on('ready', function(){
    ami.action('SIPpeers', {}, function(data){
      ami.on('eventPeerEntry', function(data){
        socket.on('data', function(data){
          io.emit('data', data);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
exports.io = io;

(...)

//Execute main
http.listen(7777, function(){
  console.log("Running...");
});
```

**[EDIT]**
After the help of Vaterrenanburg, this is the right code:

asterisk.io

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  ami.action('SIPpeers', {}, function(data){
    ami.on('eventPeerEntry', function(data){
      socket.emit("peer", data);
    });
  });
});
```

html file:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
    socket.on('peer', function (data) {
        (...)
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have it set up so that the server emits the `data` event only when the client emits the `data` event. I believe from your description that you want the server to emit the `data` event to the client on the ami `eventPeerEntry` event. To do this, remove the subscription to the `data` event on the server.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  ami.on('ready', function(){
    ami.action('SIPpeers', {}, function(data){
      ami.on('eventPeerEntry', function(data){
        io.emit('data', data);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. You were right! I had to change the Front end so that it would receive. So I had to make a small change in the server code to send data.

Comment: I'm glad my post helped you find the solution! If there is an answer that answers your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question. I'd leave this comment on your question, but I do not yet have enough reputation.